# How to get the closing event of .net core console application?

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, backend

I am using .net core console application as my backend API and react js as my frontend.
Now there is a scenario where I want to notify the react app that the API is closing or not running so that react app can perform some actions on it.

So is it possible to get the closing event of the .net core console application?

How it can be done?

Please suggest some approach for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to `ApplicationStopping` Lifetime event.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers()

var app = builder.Build();

app.Lifetime
   .ApplicationStopping
   .Register(() => Console.WriteLine("Application Stopping"));

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

However, instead of notifying your front-end that your back-end is down, you may want to implement high availability on your back-end by scaling out your API.